# Differentiation from FFT finding extrema

Tags: matlab, differentiation

I'm trying to find zeros of a function. See my code below.

Because `fft` expects a numerical array, I didn't define the symbolic function to use `fzero`.

However, this approach is not accurate and depend on `step`. Do you have a better idea?

```
step=2000;
x=0:pi/step:2*pi;
y= 4+5*cos(10*x)+20*cos(40*x)+cos(100*x);
fy = fft(y');
fy(1:8) =0;
fy(12:end-10)=0; 
fy(end-6:end)=0;
ffy = ifft(fy);
t=diff(ffy);
x=0:pi/step:2*pi-pi/step;
plot(x,t)
indices= find(t<5e-4 & t>-5e-4);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could proceed along the array `t` and look for points where the values change sign. That would indicate the presence of a zero.

Actaully, MATLAB's `fzero` function uses a similar method. You said you didn't use it because you required an array, rather than an anonymous function, but you could convert the array into an anonymous function using simple linear interpolation like so:

```
func = @(k) interp1(x,t,k);  % value of t(x) interpolated at x=k
fzero(func,initial_value);
```

**EDIT :** Just to clarify what I mean. If you have an array `t` and you want to find its zeros...

```
f = 5;                            % frequency of wave in Hz
x = 0:0.01:1;                     % time index
t = cos( 2*pi*f*x );              % cosine wave of frequency f

zeroList = [];                    % start with an empty list of zeros
for i = 2:length(t)               % loop through the array t

    current_t = t(i);             % current value of t
    previous_t = t(i-1);          % previous value of t

    if current_t == 0                  % the case where the zero is exact
        newZero = x(i);
        zeroList = [zeroList,newZero];
    elseif current_t*previous_t < 0    % a and b have opposite sign if a*b is -ve
        % do a linear interpolation to find the zero (solve y=mx+b)
        slope = (current_t-previous_t)/(x(i)-x(i-1));
        newZero = x(i) - current_t/slope;
        zeroList = [zeroList,newZero];
    end

end

figure(1); hold on;
axis([ min(x) max(x) -(max(abs(t))) (max(abs(t))) ]); 
plot(x,t,'b');
plot(x,zeros(length(x)),'k-.');
scatter(zeroList,zeros(size(zeroList)),'ro');
```

The zeros I get are correct:

[image]

Comment: Nice, it works. Is there any way to find all zeros within the given interval like [0 2pi]? or I should make a loop and try different sub-intervals?

Comment: I would loop over all the elements in the array and have a variable that remembers the previous element. If the current and previous elements differ in sign, you've found a zero.

Comment: element save the index? change of sign in different zeros? I did not get.